# If I define summation recursively, how do I prove formally that both of the following definitions are equivalent?

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, definition, recursion

First definition:

$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)=f(b)+\sum_{x=a}^{b-1} f(x)$ if $a\leq b$, and equals $0$ otherwise

Second definition:

$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b} f(x)$ if $a\leq b$, and equals $0$ otherwise

Intuitively, I have no doubt that both statements are always equal, but I am struggling to come up with a formal proof for it. I tried induction over $b$, but only got so far on working with the second definition:

$\sum_{x=a}^{b+1} f(x)=f(b+1)+\sum_{x=a}^{b}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove it formally, by strong induction on $b - a$. If $b - a < 0$, then both definitions produce $0$, so we consider only the case where $b - a \ge 0$, allowing us to use strong induction.

Let's be clear about the predicate we're proving. Let $R(f,a,b)$ and $L(f, a, b)$ be the result of applying the two respective definitions to $\sum_{x=a}^b f(x)$ (in case it's not entirely obvious, $R$ is for "right" and $L$ is for "left", to represent from where we're stripping off terms). We are claiming that:
$$P(n) : (\forall a)(\forall b)(\forall f)\Big(a - b = n \implies R(f, a, b) = L(f, a, b)\Big).$$

The base cases I wish to start from are $P(0)$ and $P(1)$. First, we tackle $P(0)$. Assuming $a - b = 0$,
$$R(f, a, b) = R(f, a, a) = R(f, a, a - 1) + f(a) = 0 + f(a),$$
and
$$L(f, a, a) = f(a) + L(f, a + 1, a) = f(a) + 0.$$
Next, if $a - b = 1$, then
$$R(f, a, b) = R(f, a, a + 1) = R(a, a) + f(a + 1) = f(a) + f(a + 1) + 0,$$
and similarly for $L(f, a)$.

Now, let's fix $n \ge 2$, and suppose that $P(k)$ is true for $k < n$. To prove $P(k)$, let us suppose $a$ and $b$ such that $b - a = n$, and $f$ is some function. Now,
$$L(f, a, b) = f(a) + L(a + 1, b).$$
Because $b - (a + 1) = n - 1 < n$, we therefore know that $L(a + 1, b) = R(a + 1, b)$, so
$$L(f, a, b) = f(a) + R(a + 1, b) = f(a) + R(a + 1, b - 1) + f(b).$$
A similar argument shows
$$R(f, a, b) = f(a) + L(a + 1, b - 1) + f(b),$$
which is equal to the quantity above, since $b - 1 - (a + 1) = n - 2 < n$ (note: we needed the assumption that $n \ge 2$ to ensure that two terms can be pulled out this way, hence the need for double base case). Thus, the induction step is completed, and the result is proven by strong induction.

Answer (score 2):

We do induction by the number $a-b+1$ of summands.
We start with the definition of the sum:
$$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x):=\sum_{x=a}^{b-1} f(x)+f(b)$$
and we want to prove
$$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b} f(x)$$
For $b-a+1=1$ and $b-a+1=2$ the statement can be easily verified, so let us assume $b-a+1\gt3$. Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)  
\\ \text{by definition of the sum we have} &
\\=f(b)+\sum_{x=a}^{b-1} f(x)  \tag 1
\\\text{so by the induction hypothesis we have}  
\\=f(b)+\left(f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} f(x)\right) \tag 2
\\=f(a)+\left(f(b)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} f(x)\right) \tag 3
\\\text{and again by definition of the sum}
\\=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b} f(x) \tag 4
\end{align}$$

We have chosen $b-a+1\ge3$ in the proof to guarantee that $\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} f(x)$ has at least one summand.

Comment: The problem doing it that way is proving the equivalence. That means you can either use the first way (and show it's the same as second way) or use the second way (and show it's the same as first way). If you are using the first way, the last statement is illegal (since uses the second way) and if you use the second way, the second statement is illegal... not sure there is a good way out of this

Comment: @gt6989b Im am not sure if I understand you right. I show that if $$\sum_{x=a}^{b-1} f(x)=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} f(x)$$ is already shown (the induction hypothesis) then 
$$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b} f(x)$$
follows. What is wrong?

Comment: I added numbers to the equation. What equation is not correct in my post?

Comment: In Theo Bandit's notation what is written is the following
$$R(f,a,b) \stackrel{def}{=} R(f,a,b-1) + f(b) \stackrel{hyp}{=} L(f,a,b-1) + f(b) \stackrel{def}{=} f(a) + L(f,a+1,b-1) + f(b) \stackrel{hyp}{=} f(a) + R(f,a+1,b-1) + f(b) \stackrel{def}{=} f(a) + R(f,a+1,b).$$ I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Ennar you are using 2 different definitions - i don't think you can do that. To prove equivalence, you have to use only one definition to get the sum to be some number, and then only other definition to evaluate the same sum, and then prove the numbers are the same.

Comment: @gt6989b, yes, but it's induction hypothesis that those two definitions coincide up to some fixed number of summands and we are proving that they coincide in the next step as well. I made it clear where definition(s) and where induction hypothesis is used. But let's be clear, miracle173 is not using two definitions, I just used extra notation to perhaps more transparently show what they are doing.

Comment: @gt6989b what miracle173 is doing is showing by induction that $R$ satisfies the same recurrence relation as $L$, and with same initial conditions, so by recursion theorem these two functions coincide.

Answer (score 0):

First, we assume $a,b$ are integers (and so must be finite). If $a > b$, both sums yield $0$ (and thus agree), so assume $a \le b$.

---

A, intuitive direct approach is to apply the recursion. You have with the first definition:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{x=a}^b f(x)
 &= f(a) + \sum_{x=a+1}^b f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \sum_{x=a+2}^b f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + \sum_{x=b}^b f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b) + \sum_{x=b+1}^b f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b) + 0 \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b)
\end{split}
$$
The second definition yields
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{x=a}^b f(x)
 &= f(b) + \sum_{x=a}^{b-1} f(x) \\
 &= f(b-1) + f(b) + \sum_{x=a}^{b-2} f(x) \\
 &= f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b) + \sum_{x=a}^a f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b) + \sum_{x=a-1}^a f(x) \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b) + 0 \\
 &= f(a) + f(a+1) + \ldots + f(b-1) + f(b)
\end{split}
$$
so the sums agree.

---

A more formal approach is to use induction on the number of terms.

Comment: Intuitively it makes sense, but I am struggling to come up with a more formal approach to proving this. Could you maybe edit your answer to include the induction on the number of terms?

Comment: that dot notation does not make sense if the user requests a formal proof for his statement

Comment: I see now that you wrote an "intuitive" approach. So it makes sense